# Как удалить элемент, в котором находится кнопка на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, вёрстка

Существует три квадрата. в каждом находиться кнопка.
Добился удаления квадратов по клику на них, но не по кнопке.
Классы у них одинаковые. Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
const testDel = document.querySelector('.delis')
const testBlock = document.querySelector('.block')
const famBlock = document.querySelector('.blockCont');

famBlock.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('block')) {
    famBlock.removeChild(e.target)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="blockCont">
  <div class="block red"><button class="delis">удалить</button></div>
  <div class="block yellow"><button class="delis">удалить</button></div>
  <div class="block blue"><button class="delis">удалить</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let famBlock = document.querySelector('.blockCont');
let blocks = famBlock.querySelectorAll('.block');

blocks.forEach((block) => {
  let buttonDel = block.querySelector('.delis');
  buttonDel.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    ev.target.closest('.block').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="blockCont">
  <div class="block red"><button class="delis">удалить1 </button></div>
  <div class="block yellow"><button class="delis">удалить2 </button></div>
  <div class="block blue"><button class="delis">удалить3 </button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, не додумался.  буду знать

Answer (score 0):

```js
const testDel = document.querySelector('.delis')
const testBlock = document.querySelector('.block')
const famBlock = document.querySelector('.blockCont');

famBlock.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('block')) {
    famBlock.removeChild(e.target)
  }
})

document.querySelectorAll('.block .delis').forEach(
  b => b.addEventListener('click', (e) => b.closest('.block').remove())
);
```

```css
.block {
  padding: 10px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
  
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
  
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockCont">
  <div class="block red"><button class="delis">удалить</button></div>
  <div class="block yellow"><button class="delis">удалить</button></div>
  <div class="block blue"><button class="delis">удалить</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Короткая запись

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockCont">
  <div class="block red"><button class="delis" onclick='this.parentElement.remove();'>удалить</button></div>
  <div class="block yellow"><button class="delis" onclick='this.parentElement.remove();'>удалить</button></div>
  <div class="block blue"><button class="delis" onclick='this.parentElement.remove();'>удалить</button></div>
</div>
```